# For what is better suited every type of communication in Unix sockets?

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming

I need to build a server using Unix domain sockets, and it looks that there are several options to choose the kind of communication.
From `man 2 socket`:

- SOCK_STREAM
- SOCK_DGRAM
- SOCK_SEQPACKET

So, for what is better suited every one of them? (stream, datagram, packet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what kind of server you are going to implement.

If message boundaries are important, then `SOCK_DGRAM` would be the best choice.
Because `recvfrom/recvmsg/select` will return when a complete message is received.

With `SOCK_STREAM`, message receiving is more tricky: One receiving call may return a partial message, or part of two messages, or several messages... etc.

If message boundaries are not important, then `SOCK_STREAM` could be the best choice.

`SOCK_DGRAM` of `AF_INET` is unreliable UDP. But, in most sytems, `SOCK_DGRAM` of `AF_UNIX` is reliable. 
For example: If queue of receiver is full, sender will be blocked until there is space.

Answer (score 0):

For TCP -> SOCK_STREAM
For UDP -> SOCK_DGRAM

Comment: But I'm referring about connections via Unix sockets

Comment: But the same basic ideas apply to AF_UNIX sockets. `man 7 unix` gives a little more information. SOCK_STREAM means an ordered, reliable stream of bytes connected to a single peer; SOCK_DGRAM means a potentially unordered, unreliable, packet-boundary-preserving protocol that can sendto/recvfrom multiple destinations, and SOCK_SEQPACKET is like a cross between the two, connection-oriented but packet-boundary-preserving.